# How to use Asp.Net Core 1.0.1 binaries

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, installation, binaries

I just downloaded binaries for Asp.Net Core 1.0.1 from https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/1.0. Where do I put these binaries on my Windows-computer so I can run that version? I have experimented with placing it in various subfolders of the dotnet-folder but I don't get it to work when I run the application (an application from a book I am studying - John Cilibertis "Asp.Net Core Recipes"). Where do I put these binaries - from what I have read binaries do not need an installer, they should just be put in the appropriate folder? But which folder is that?